# Not Authorized to delete a user with Google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to delete a User from our Google domain (G Suite for Education) with Google script inside a Drive-Project. I'm logged on as the 'super-admin', have activated APIs for the Project etc. I can create users, add group membership, set OU-path etc.

When I try to delete a test user with the same Project I'm "not authorized"?

Code:

```
var userEmail = 'testaccount1@mydomain.se';
var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail);

user = AdminDirectory.Users.remove(user);
Logger.log('User: ' + userEmail + ' deleted.');
```

Any ideas?
Sorry if this is a stupid question! I'm a Google script-beginner. ;-)
Kind regards,
/Sverker (Sweden)

Comment: I found a solution, trial and error. I works when I'm refering to the user by the users mail. I can't refer to the user by var user. I don'y understans why, but It works...

Comment: function testDelUser() {    //Test deleting a user
  
  var userEmail = 'xmates00@utb.ostragoinge.se';
  var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail);  //I can skip this line
   
   //it works when I refer to the user by it's primary mail? I can'n use var user...?
   //var response = AdminDirectory.Users.remove(user); //This line does not work???
   var delete_user = AdminDirectory.Users.remove(userEmail); //This works Ok???
   
   Logger.log('User:' + userEmail + ' deleted, response: ' + delete_user);
  
}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should post your working code as an *answer* and select it. That way, when someone else has a similar question, there's an answer here for them.